# Google OAuth Consent Screen - Wrong Scopes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scopes

**My problem:**
Wrong scopes in OAuth Consent Screen.

Some screenshots:

The Consent Screen from my phone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4aVr.png

From Google Cloud Platform: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY4VK.png

My game is in testing status.

**1.** I want keep **only** the Google Play Game Services and the Google Drive scopes.

**2.** Also, how can I make Google Play Game Services and the Google Drive scopes **mandatory**, like the three first scopes?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which scopes are you requesting when you authorize the client? You cannot make scopes mandatory. Instead check which scopes were authorized and then inform the user, fail authorization, etc. Edit your question with the requested information.

Answer (score 1):

It's fixed!
I was using a plugin that was handling the sign-in, so I removed it's default requests (email, id etc.).